# How to remove status bar located at the bottom of ST3

Tags: sublimetext3, statusbar

I did a research on this over the internet but I did see how to do this. I just want to hide/remove the status bar at the bottom of my text editor (sublime text 3), that shows the line and column and etc. Please see the image below:

[image]

BTW, I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status bar in Sublime can be hidden using the `View > Hide Status Bar` menu command or the `View: Toggle Status Bar` command in the Command Palette. The state of the status bar is specific to the window, so you need to use the command in all of your windows if you have more than one (assuming you want it off everywhere).

Note that the presence of the status bar in a new Sublime window depends on the state of the status bar in the existing window that has the focus when the new window is created.

As a result of that, if you have more than one window you need to use the command in all of the windows in order to have it permanently turned off.